# Odoo : Outcomin Mail Server

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I use Odoo 10 installed on VM , i have this problem with Outcoming Mail Server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2pHE.png)

Comment: I doubt this question is related with programming. See [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Does your VM definitely have DNS resolution set up correctly? Can you `dig` or `ping` smtp.gmail.com from a shell on the VM?

Comment: How can i know that my VM definitely have DNS resolution set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello @Koussay Abdouli**

Please change the port to 465 and check again.

**Configuration:**

Gmail Server: smtp.gmail.com

Port: SSL – 465 / STARTTLS – 587

Answer (score 0):

You should put 465 into the smtp port used by google:

[image: Generate app password]

Then create google application password and insert those informations into Security and Authentication menu:

[image: outgoing mail server]